# DocuSign - How to handle system downtime

Tags: docusignapi

When we maintenance our server, or redeploy our external facing REST services for DocuSign, is there a way we can lock all envelopes that are currently sitting with signers? We use Connect to process signer/document updates from DocuSign, and we don't want these requests coming through while we're under maintenance.

I've seen in the documentation we can lock individual envelopes. Is the best route to run through each envelope that's still pending signature and temporarily lock it? This method seems very resource intensive considering the amount of consecutive API calls needed.

Answer (score 0):

Connect supports exponential retires when the events fail to be sent to your endpoint. How long does your system down time take exactly?

When your system is back up, new events should arrive in your endpoint and you can react to them accordingly. Please let us know if you see otherwise.

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/architecture